# Validation for duplicate record

Tags: mysql, validation, javafx

I have some problem when doing validation for my rating system. So basically what I am trying to do is one user only can vote for once for each product, either vote up or vote down and I am doing in 3 tier.

My sql statement to validate for the vote record based on each productID and user name:

```
public boolean validateRate(){
    boolean result = false;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.getConnection();
    String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM sm_productrate WHERE productID =" + prodID + " AND custName = '" + custName + "' AND productRateUp = 1 OR productRateDown = 1";
    rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
    try {
        if (rs.next()) {
            result = true;
        }else{
            result = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.terminate();
    return result;
 }
```

And this is my submit like and dislike method together with the validate method of the calling of the sql method above:

```
 public boolean submitLike(CreateReviewAndRateUI panel,int row){
    String custName = panel.getUserLoggedLbl().getText();
    shopManagement.entity.Product product = new shopManagement.entity.Product(row, custName);
    boolean result = product.validateRate();
    if(result == true){
         Dialogs.showErrorDialog(null, "You have already voted once for this product", "Duplicate rate record found", ""); 
         result = true;
    }else{
        product.submitLike();
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean submitDislike(CreateReviewAndRateUI panel,int row){
    String custName = panel.getUserLoggedLbl().getText();
    shopManagement.entity.Product product = new shopManagement.entity.Product(row, custName);
    boolean result = product.validateRate();
    if(result == true){
        Dialogs.showErrorDialog(null, "You have already voted once for this product", "Duplicate rate record found", "");    
    }else{
        product.submitDislike(); 
    }       
    return result;
}

public boolean validateRate(CreateReviewAndRateUI panel, int row){
    String custName = panel.getUserLoggedLbl().getText();
    Product product = new Product(row, custName);
    boolean result = product.validateRate();
   return result;
}
```

And this is when the button on click, it will call the methods above accordingly.

```
@FXML
public void submitLike(ActionEvent event){
    int row = Integer.parseInt(getGetRowLbl().getText());
    CreateReviewAndRateController controller = new CreateReviewAndRateController();
    boolean result = controller.submitLike(myPane,row);

    if(!result){
        Dialogs.showInformationDialog(null, "Up vote has been successfully sunmitted",
                "Successful Submission", "");
        displayRate(row);
        getLikeBtn().setDisable(true);
        getDislikeBtn().setDisable(true);
    }
}

@FXML
public void submitDislike(ActionEvent event){
    int row = Integer.parseInt(getGetRowLbl().getText());
    CreateReviewAndRateController controller = new CreateReviewAndRateController();
    boolean result = controller.submitDislike(myPane,row);
     if(!result){
        Dialogs.showInformationDialog(null, "Down vote has been successfully sunmitted",
                "Successful Submission", "");
        displayRate(row);
        getLikeBtn().setDisable(true);
        getDislikeBtn().setDisable(true);
    }
}
```

However, there's a very strange thing happened. For example, my first user to enter the rate is Dean. Everything works perfectly, it can add the rate record into database, can validate without any problem. But when I change the user logged, and I tried to insert a rate record into database, it does not works, it keeps prompting me the duplicate record found error message but in fact, there's no rate record for the second users in database. Then after that, I log in with the first user which is Dean again, and I choose a product without any rate record. And yet, it does not works as well. I wonder where did I coded wrongly. Hope my explanation for my problem is clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM sm_productrate WHERE productID =" + prodID + 
    " AND custName = '" + custName + "' AND (productRateUp = 1 OR productRateDown = 1)";
```